# How many points does 'the-most-point-contained-circle' contain at least?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

> **Question** : Given any $n$ distinct points $S$, consider the $\binom n2$ discs $D_{pq}$ formed by picking a pair of points $p,q$ from $S$ and using them as a diameter. For each disc $D_{pq}$, let $N_{pq}$ be the number of points of $S$ on or inside $D_{pq}$. Let $N_S(n)$ be the largest $N_{pq}$, i.e. 
>   $$N_S(n)=\max\{N_{pq} :p,q\in S,p\not=q\}.$$
>   Let $f(n)$ be the minimum value of $N_S(n)$ when $S$ varies over the set of $n$ points. Then, how can we represent $f(n)$ by $n$ ?

**Remark** : This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829017/how-many-points-does-the-most-point-contained-circle-contain-at-least) with receiving only a partial answer.

On math.SE, a user achille hui got the following bounds for $n\gt 3$ : 
$$\left\lceil \frac{n}{3}\right\rceil + 1 \le f(n) \le \left\lceil\frac{2n}{3}\right\rceil.$$

This fixes $f(4)$ to $3$. (We have $f(3)=2,f(5)=3$, but I don't know $f(6),f(7),\cdots$.)

However, no more answers have been received.

The question comes from that I changed 'rectangle' to 'circle' in the following question.

"When we place $n$ distinct points on the $xy$-plane, prove that there exists a rectangle, whose diagonal is closed by two of the $n$ points and whose edges are parallel to either $x$-axis or $y$-axis, has at least $\lfloor(n+1)/5\rfloor+1$ points inside or on the edges."

I would like to know how to find $f(n)$ (or better bounds), and any relevant references.